# Error while sending AT command from stm32 to sim 800

Tags: stm32

I am trying to send AT command to stm32 but I am getting error while sending AT command

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include <string>
Serial pc(SERIAL_TX, SERIAL_RX); // pc comunication
Serial SIM900(PA_9, PA_10);   //tx, rx SIM 900
string result;
char x;

void clearString()
 {
  result.clear();
 }

 }
void controlAT()
{ 
 clearString();  
 wait_ms(100);      
 SIM900.printf("AT\r");
 wait_ms(1000); 
 if(result=="\r\nOK\r\n") {
 pc.printf("\r\n----OK AT----\r\n");
}else {
 pc.printf("-- ERROR AT --");           //this is a error
 }
 pc.printf("%s",result.c_str());     
 }

void sendSMS()
{
 pc.printf("\r\n----sendSMS2----\r\n");  
 clearString();
 SIM900.printf("AT+CMGS=");
 SIM900.printf("\"");
 SIM900.printf("074xxxxx");   
 SIM900.printf("\"");
 SIM900.printf("\r");
 wait_ms(200);      // this create the problem
 SIM900.printf("Hello");
 SIM900.printf("\r");
 SIM900.putc(0x1A); 
 wait_ms(200);
 pc.printf("%s",result.c_str());       
 clearString(); 

}


int main() {    

pc.printf("\r\n GSM 900 TEST\n"); 

SIM900.baud(9600)
wait_ms(200);


 controlAT();
 wait_ms(200);
 sendSMS();  // SEND SMS     
 wait_ms(200);      



}
```

I am getting error in  controlAT() function and it always printing 
pc.printf("-- ERROR AT --");           //this is a error

Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks wrong, u clear "result" but u never set it.

There should be a line like...
    result=SIM900.print...

Comment: but in below link it says it working    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31454683/send-sms-with-stm32l152-and-sim900